# Dutch citizenship for my son. His grandmother still has Dutch citizenship

Tags: passport, children

I want to know whether my son is able to be eligible for a Dutch passport. My Grandmother still lives in Holland (she is 108 years old!!) and my mother lives in South Africa. She still has a Dutch passport and has citizenship. She still votes in Netherland and visits there once a year. She is 8o years old. 
My son is 17 years old and he wants to study in Holland, and a Dutch passport will make it much easier. 
Please help, because I've been through the whole process of getting a Dutch passport for me, but was then told that I am not eligible anymore. Apparently my son is still the right age. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What process did you go through? Why were you told you were no longer eligible?

Comment: If you are not eligible for Dutch nationality "anymore," then you had Dutch nationality and lost it.  If that is the case, your son would only have gained Dutch nationality if you were Dutch at the time of his birth.  That is, if you lost Dutch nationality after he was born, then he is probably Dutch.  The best way to find out whether he's eligible is to apply at the Dutch consulate.  If they told you when you lost your Dutch nationality then you should be able to determine whether it's worthwhile to make the application.

Comment: Oh, sorry... What I meant was that I could have applied for citizenship a few years ago, but it is not possible anymore because of my age. Neither me nor him were Dutch at the time of birth, but my mother was and still is. Thanks so much for your answer! X

Comment: If you were not Dutch when he was born then I fear there is little hope. There is no provision in Dutch nationality law for acquiring Dutch nationality on the basis of a grandparent.  You should be sure that you were not Dutch, however.  On what basis did you lose your Dutch nationality?

Comment: I was born in South Africa. My mother came to SA after she was 18 years old, but never gave up her Dutch citizenship. I assume I am a SA citizen, seeing that I was born here.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your subsequent comment until now.  If you include `@phoog` in your reply to my comment, I will get a notification that you replied so I won't miss it.  If your mother was Dutch when you were born then you were Dutch when you were born *as well as South African.* If you are "not eligible anymore" then you must have lost your Dutch nationality at some point after your birth.  I asked about why you lost Dutch nationality to shed some light on the timing.

Answer (score 1):

When your window of time to acquire citizenship elapsed, that ended line of citizenship according to [Dutch Nationality Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_nationality_law). Your son will have to go through the typical visa routes to study in Holland.

Comment: Unless she lost her Dutch nationality after her son was born, in which case he is Dutch.